# Double click event in a treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, treeview, double-click

My client requirement is to use single click to select a node and then double click to transfer the node to another treeview. Is this possible with the .NET treeview control?

Comment: you can try this by using java script [ondblclick Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp) Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/3106189.aspx) answer.

Comment: problem is the double click event is needed for the child nodes on and the TreeNode class doesn't have a properties to add an attribute. I try also adding the attribute to the main treeview but I won't be able to get the value of the selected node.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid asp.net tree view control do not support it.
For this kind of question, I suggest 2 solutions:

1. Use 3rd control. Most commercial controls provide more features.
2. Use pure client side control. Typically you can find them in jQuery. But you need do some mapping work for you server side code.

Comment: I'm looking at telerik now but they are very pricey. Do you know any alternative 3rd party controls?

Comment: Yes, telerik is a very powerful one. I do not have any good alternative for you. In .net world, most of the things are expensive, especial for controls. Because Control is very easy to be a product. I suggest you use Jquery client tree control instead. In fact, if you have javascript background, you will know the server side program model which asp.net provides can be done by yourself. What you can do is write some javascript to write the value in some hiddens and then get them in the server side.